# export/import dataset to markdown to run with stargazer

Tags: r

I want to import one of my huge datasets into markdown to generate a table in latex via stargazer by exporting it as .csv. The problem is that it doesn´t render the way I want it - it just shows the latex code and not the table.

````
df<-mtcars
write.csv(df, file="df.csv")


---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
output:
    pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(stargazer)    
temp <- read.csv("df.csv")
stargazer(temp, type = 'latex')
````

If i just use the built in 'mtcars' everthing works fine.

````
stargazer(mtcars, type = 'latex')
```
````

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Does `{r, result = 'asis'}` solve the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, just getting this "raw" format:

#### % Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu## % Date and time: Mån, Maj 11, 2020 - 20:39:05## \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering##   \caption{}##   \label{}## \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc}## \\[-1.8ex]\hline## \hline \\[-1.8ex]## Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} &